# Why is my join not returning anything?

Tags: mysql

Involved Entities:

**Rental**
Id(PK), BorrowerId, BookId, CheckOutWorkerId, CheckOutDate, DueDate, CheckInWorkerId, CheckInDate

**Worker**
BannerId(PK), FirstName, LastName, Credentials

**StudentBorrower**
BannerId(PK), FirstName, LastName, BorrowerStatus

**Book**
Barcode(PK), Title, Author

So I am having issues trying to join two tables together. The rental entity could have two different workers in the table. So I tried this and it yielded an empty table when there should be well over 30 different rows. Any ideas?

```
SELECT Rental.Id, Book.Title AS BookRented, 
    CONCAT(StudentBorrower.FirstName, ' ', StudentBorrower.LastName) AS 
    RentedBy, Rental.CheckOutDate, CONCAT(w1.FirstName, ' ', w1.LastName) AS CheckedOutBy, 
    Rental.DueDate, Rental.CheckInDate, CONCAT(w2.FirstName, ' ', w2.LastName AS CheckedInBy 
FROM Rental
    JOIN Book 
        ON Book.Barcode = Rental.BookId 
    JOIN StudentBorrower 
        ON StudentBorrower.BannerId = Rental.BorrowerId
    JOIN Worker w1
        ON w1.BannerId = Rental.CheckOutWorkerId
    JOIN Worker w2
        ON w2.BannerId = Rental.CheckInWorkerId
ORDER BY Rental.Id ASC
```

Comment: probably an OUTER JOIN is required on one of those tables where there is no linking data..

Comment: provide sample of raw data or even better sql fiddle  with data

Comment: If a book has been checked out but not yet checked in, it won't show up because the last join won't match anything.

Comment: That makes sense.. I will have to try and find out a way to do this..